# generated (compiled) ng-click buttons throw "scope.$apply is not a function"

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Been playing around with this a bit, and get a very strange error. 
I will not put the whole code here, because there are way to much spagetti all over the place, but I think I can isolate the code.

I have some code that generates a bunch of buttons on the screen based on some variables from the database. Mostly links, but I want the database to hold information on what to do with it. So I want my function to:
Get data from the database   (done)
Find some additional entries, binary sound and image (done)
Draw a pretty button (it ain't pretty, but it is a button)
Create a ng-click event for when the user presses the button (1st step done)
compile the html to sort out the dom for ng-click (it runs...)

All this seems to work, and I get a button on the screen, but when I press it I get the below error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: scope.$apply is not a function
```

The code that does it (simplified):

```
            var newPad = '<button class="padbtn" ';
            newPad = newPad + 'data-ng-click="'+dataPad.comSound+'('+dataPad.typeSound+','+padPos+')">';
            newPad = newPad + '<img class="padImg" src="/api/getImg/'+dataPad.srcImage+'" style="width:175px; height 175px;"/>'
            newPad = newPad + '<br/>'+dataPad.name+'</button>';
            console.log(newPad);
            var padElement = $compile(newPad)(true);
            console.log(padElement);
            $('#cell'+padPos).append(padElement);
```

To make it simpler to reproduce (and self contained)

```
var newPad = '<button class="padbtn" data-ng-click="playBeat(smpBeat,C1)"><img class="padImg" src="/api/getImg/554240a17b221e1a2ffda099" style="width:175px; height 175px;"/><br/>Clap</button>'
                var padElement = $compile(newPad)(true);
            $('#targetID').append(padElement);
```

Picture and everything loads, but once I press the button I get that error message.

Comment: it think you `var padElement = $compile(newPad)(true);` should be `var padElement = $compile(newPad)(scope);` which should compile with current scope

Comment: does your code is in compile or in link function?

Comment: use This `var padElement = $compile(newPad)($scope);`

Comment: Think you where all right (well you said the same thing). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you must compile the `$scope`

```
    var newPad = '<button class="padbtn" data-ng-click="playBeat(smpBeat,C1)"><img class="padImg" src="/api/getImg/554240a17b221e1a2ffda099" style="width:175px; height 175px;"/><br/>Clap</button>'
    var padElement = $compile(newPad)($scope);
    $('#targetID').append(padElement);
```

See the working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vamsikrishnamannem/0zzeo6z6/3/)